# IntelliJ IDEA 15 test generation location

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use the 'create test' feature (by pressing alt-enter or ctrl-shift-t on a class name) - the automatically-generated source files end up in the 'main' source directory, and thus are included in a release build.

My project already has a 'test' directory present -- I'm not sure why the tests can't be automatically placed there.

I have searched around in IDEA and online but there does not seem to be any obvious way to correct this.

Any ideas?

Comment: The term "branch" is normally used to refer to version control branches, and it doesn't look like you're using it in that meaning. What is "test" actually? Is it a directory or a module?

Comment: They are directories, updating question.